# which dimm sockets are of the upper 2G?

Tags: memory, hardware-failure

I have an ASUS motherboard with 4 memory sockets, now with 4G memory.

DIMM A1 and DIMM B1, which are yellow.

DIMM A2 and DIMM B2, which are black.

I have 25 errors in my upper 2G so I want to get rid of them.

Which sockets contain the modules for the upper 2G?

Comment: Just a thought, but have you tried testing the ram sticks one at a time on a different machine ? The issue might not be your RAM, but your motherboard, or CPU.

Comment: It were the black ones. And, some whisky cleaned the upper 2G so that they now work.